# iOS <-> Android socket communication

Tags: android, ios, sockets

I'm working on an app that needs to be able to sync its own data with that of another installation on a completely different device.  The remote device can potentially be Android, iOS or Windows, and it's supposed to sync without issue.  Pretty standard stuff overall.  The idea is for one device to send a request for the other devices data, which compiles it and sends it back, then the first device processes it, stores what it needs locally, then sends its own data that the second device doesn't have over to the second device.

I got it up and running fairly well using UDP broadcasts for IPs, then XML over TCP sockets.  Absolutely nothing special about it.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work in one particular case.  Specifically, that of communicating with an iOS device.  There's two particular cases in play here.  The first, where android serves as the first device (the client) in the above description works perfectly.  There's absolutely no issues whatsoever.  But the second, where android serves as the second device (the server), fails on the final transfer.

It behaves as if I can only read a send from the iOS device once, and never again.  It's only the first write per socket that I can read, even though, from what I can tell from tcpdump logs and whatnot, the data *is* being written to the tcp stack by the iOS device.  Android flat out doesn't register that it's there.  A straight socket.getInputStream().read() hangs infinitely waiting for data.

I have no idea what the problem could be, beyond a vague suspicion that iOS sockets do some kind of screwy Apple shenanigans that are getting in the way, seeing as this same issue occurs when iOS tries to sync with Windows.

Has anyone ever encountered an issue like this and have any idea how to go about solving it?  Or even just knowledge of what side of the equation is causing the problem?

Thank you very much in advance.

Here's some code, since people in the comments asked:

```
        server = new ServerSocket(portNum);
        socket = server.accept();

        byte[] lenBuffer = new byte[4];
        socket.getInputStream().read(lenBuffer, 0, lenBuffer.length);
        int lengthToRead = ByteBuffer.wrap(lenBuffer).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getInt();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

        int totalReadSoFar = 0;
        String line;
        while( totalReadSoFar < lengthToRead && (line = reader.readLine()) != null  ){
            buffer.append(line);
            totalReadSoFar += line.getBytes().length + 1;
        }

        if( buffer.toString().equals("syncCommand") )
            syncOverSocket(socket);
```

And syncOverSocket is here:

```
    String xml = buildXml(outSyncData);

    byte[] encryptedData = encryptXml(xml, localPin);
    encryptedData = Base64.encode(encryptedData, Base64.NO_WRAP);

    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    byteBuffer.putInt(encryptedData.length);
    byte[] bytes = byteBuffer.array();
    dataOutputStream.write(bytes);
    dataOutputStream.write(encryptedData);
    dataOutputStream.flush();

    byte[] lenBuffer = new byte[4];
    socket.getInputStream().read(lenBuffer, 0, lenBuffer.length);
    int lengthToRead = ByteBuffer.wrap(lenBuffer).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getInt();

    byte[] finalResult = new byte[0];
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int totalReadSoFar = 0;
    int justRead;
    while( totalReadSoFar < lengthToRead && (justRead = socket.getInputStream().read(buffer, 0, 1024)) > -1 ){
        finalResult = concat(finalResult, buffer, justRead);
        totalReadSoFar += justRead;
    }
```

The problem is the final "socket.getInputStream().read(lenBuffer, 0, lenBuffer.length);".  It reaches that line without error, then hangs forever waiting for data.  Something is blocking the data from coming through, either by the iOS device not sending properly, or the Android device not reading from the socket correctly, and I can't honestly tell what.

Comment: You should provide us with some of the code

Comment: This question only needed one sentence of the seven paragraphs above, and a block of code to show what you tried and the unexpected error.

Comment: There isn't an error.  That's the problem.  It reaches a read without issue and then hangs forever without reading anything.